# How do I center a column in tikzposter?

Tags: posters, tikzposter

Consider the following `tikzposter`. I would like to center the block horizontally so that there is equal space on the left and right sides of the block. I have tried using `\centering` and also using `hglue` before the block statement, but it does not appear to achieve the desired effect.

**How can I center the block horizontally?**

```
\documentclass[25pt, portrait]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=30in,paperheight=40in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Live Demo}
\author{
    \large
    merlin2011
}

\date{\today}
\institute{No Name University}
\usepackage{comment}

\usetheme{Board}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.8}
    \block{Center This Block}{
        \centering
    }
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

```
\documentclass[25pt, portrait]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=30in,paperheight=40in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Live Demo}
\author{
    \large
    merlin2011
}

\date{\today}
\institute{No Name University}
\usepackage{comment}

\usetheme{Board}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
\column{0.1}
\column{0.8}
\block{Center This Block}{}
\column{0.1}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]